# Set a Server-Wide Session Variable?

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to "turn off" my website by setting a simple session variable that is either "ON' or "OFF".

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['STATUS'] = "OFF";
?>
```

On every other page, the website checks if STATUS is off and redirects the user to a "We're Closed" page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['STATUS'] == "OFF") {
        echo "<script>window.location='http://*****/sorry/';</script>";
    }
?>
```

The problem is that the session variable that I set is exclusive to *my* session, and any other clients that also might be browsing the site are left unaffected by the change. Is there a way to set a server-wide session variable that affects every session?

Comment: I recommend storing a flag variable in a database or, failing that, a flat file.

Comment: It's better if you store that in database, and retrieve it in need. :)

Comment: Another option would be a cache database, which would load the configurations faster since everything is stored in memory (however, a standard database or file will probably be quicker and more standard to set up).

Comment: I recommend you look into environment variables, which can achieve this through server configuration.

Comment: @cbuckley That's not how environment variables work. They're shared across all processes that inherit them, but changes to them are **not** shared; you can't change them without doing it from the top.

Comment: @duskwuff sorry if it wasn't clear, but that's exactly what I was implying to be done - changing them in Apache config, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has no concept of "server-wide". There's only $_SESSION for per-user persistence.

You COULD set something at the webserver level. e.g. in Apache:

```
SetEnv EXAMPLE.COM_STATUS off
```

and then

```
<?php

if ($_ENV['EXAMPLE.COM_STATUS'] == 'off') {
   die("Site be gone");
}
```

And of course there's always sentinel files or other "external" markers that are even easier to set up:

```
$ touch /home/sites/example.com/kill_it_now

<?php

if (file_exists('/home/sites/example.com/kill_it_now')) {
   die("Site be gone");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP by default handles session data on a per user basis.  In order to have sessions potentially share settings or do anything other than the default behavior you would need to implement your own [Session Handler](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php).

Sessions are intended to be done on a per user basis, setting a something globally is better off being done in some sort of environment variable or any other means of setting the value in one location to be read from many sessions.